# how to create a range slider in jquery for steps as daily,weekly and monthly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a range slider which operates on dropdown menus {daily, weekly and monthly}.

On selection of daily steps are changed to 7 and minDate chages to maxDate means todays date-7. On selection of weekly steps are changed to 4(7-7-7-7=30) and minDate chages to  (maxDate)today date-30.
on selection of monthly steps are changed to 12(12 months=365 days) and minDate chages to  (maxDate)today date-365.

And both the mouse pointer pointed to maxDate

```
var maxdate1 = new Date(),
    minDate1 = removeDays(new Date(), -7);
alert(minDate1);

$( "#slider" )
  .slider({range: true,
      step:  1,
      animate:true,
      value: maxDate1,
      values [minDate1, maxDate1],
      max: Math.floor((maxDate1.getTime() - minDate1.getTime()) / 86400000),

      slide: function(event, ui) {

        var date = new Date(minDate1.getTime());
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + ui.values[0]);

        $('#startDate').val($.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', date));
        $('#from').val($.datepicker.formatDate('M d, yy', date));          

        date = new Date(minDate1.getTime());

        date.setDate(date.getDate() + ui.values[1]);

        $('#endDate').val($.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', date));
        $('#to').val($.datepicker.formatDate('M d, yy', date));
      }
  });
```

Comment: What is your question or specific problem?  Also, please indent your code for readability.

Comment: Can you clarify your question, please? Also, post a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of your problem so we have a working copy to look at.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to be able to change the parameters of the slider (e.g. step, min, max, etc.) after it's been initialized.  Something like this should work:

```
$('#dropdown').change(function() {
    switch ($(this).val()) {
    case 'daily':
        $('#slider').slider('option', 'step', 1);
        break;
    case 'weekly':
        $('#slider').slider('option', 'step', 7);
        break;
    case 'monthly':
        $('#slider').slider('option', 'step', 30);
        break;
    }
});
```